# Redundant Find All References output in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

How to fix the **Find All References** output in Visual Studio so it do not show redundant results? It should show only one occurrence of a searched value and not 4 times like in the screenshot below.

[image]

Software version: Visual Studio 2019, Version 16.4.1

**UPDATE: The problem is fixed with Visual Studio 2019, Version 16.6.3**

Comment: Why not first try an update to the latest version (currently 16.6.3) of VS2019? It this a one project solution or are there multiple projects? Is the file used in multiple projects?

Comment: The "Project" column on the screenshot have identical values. Same for "File" column.
The file is used only in one project.

Comment: Cannot reproduce here.

Comment: I will appreciate it if you could provide me with a small demo or more code.